# Run Ansible playbook on OVH cloud instance with Terraform Cloud

Tags: ansible, terraform, ssh-keys, ovh, terraform-cloud

I have a Terraform+Ansible combination that sets up an OVH cloud instance, and then runs an Ansible playbook on it using provisioners. When I run this locally, I can supply the public and private keys directly via the command line (not using file paths), and the `terraform apply` works perfectly.

On Terraform Cloud, I create the keys as variables. When I run the Terraform plan, the `remote-exec` provisioner works, and connects to the instance as it should. However, the `local-exec` fails with a `Permission denied (publickey)`. What am I missing?

My provisioner blocks:

```
# Dummy resource to hold the provisioner that runs ansible
resource "null_resource" "run_ansible" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["sudo apt update", "sudo apt install python3 -y", "echo Done!"]

    connection {
      host        = openstack_compute_instance_v2.test_instance.network[0].fixed_ip_v4
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = var.pvt_key
    }
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python3 -m pip install --no-input ansible; ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -u ubuntu -i '${openstack_compute_instance_v2.test_instance.network[0].fixed_ip_v4},' '--private-key=${var.pvt_key}' -e 'pub_key=${var.pub_key}' ansible/setup.yml"
  }
}
```

Terraform cloud run error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [xx.xxx.xxx.xx]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nno such identity: /home/tfc-agent/.tfc-agent/component/terraform/runs/run-AhaANkduM9YXJVoC/config/<<EOT\n-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----<private-key>-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\nEOT: No such file or directory\r\nubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xx: Permission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}
```

Comment: Are you running Terraform Cloud in remote execution mode?

Comment: Can you use Packer+Ansible instead?

Comment: It sure does look like your value of `private_key` has heredoc markers, which I strongly, _strongly_ suspect is a typo from elsewhere

Comment: @javierlga I am using the regular Version Control mode linked to a repository, and triggering builds manually from the workspace. I wanted to keep my cloud infrastructure independent of local key files etc.

Comment: @mdaniel It does. I took that from the Terraform docs: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#heredoc-strings

This was the only way I found I could pass the private key to `ansible-playbook` via the command line and have it work, so I assumed it would also work when passed that way by Terraform Cloud.

Comment: I'm glad it was something simple; please [add and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own answer, so others will know your problem has been resolved

Comment: @Perpetual there are two execution modes in Terraform Cloud, local and remote, when using remote it means that all the operations will run on TFC instances, therefore you have to create the public and private key using `local_sensitive_file` or `tls_private_key` and then reference the path/content in your `local-exec` provisioner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating (sensitive) key files on the Terraform Cloud host, and passing the paths to them to Ansible instead.

The variables are still supplied via TFCloud, but without the heredoc syntax.

I had to add an extra new line `\n` at the end of the key to get around it being stripped. See the following issue: https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/9082.

```
resource "local_sensitive_file" "key_file" {
    content  = "${var.pvt_key}\n"
    filename = "${path.root}/.ssh/key"
    file_permission = "600"
    directory_permission = "700"
}

resource "local_sensitive_file" "pubkey_file" {
    content  = "${var.pub_key}\n"
    filename = "${path.root}/.ssh/key.pub"
    file_permission = "644"
    directory_permission = "700"
}
```